# c# update attribute via reference or method

Tags: c#, object, methods

Bit of a noob question but:

I have a custom class defined as:

```
public class Icon
{
    string name;
int value;
public void setName(string nameIn)
{
    name = nameIn;
}
public void setValue(int valueIn)
{
    value = valueIn;
}
}
```

Is it better to update the object attributes (in this case from an array of type Icon) from another class in the same application domain using:

```
fm.iconData[0].setName("Plum");
```

OR is it better to set by changing my instance variable modifiers in the Icon class to 'public' and use:

```
fm.iconData[0].name = "Plum";
```

Is this breaking any OO design concepts?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but generally I would lean towards using properties instead of methods. `public string Name { get; set; }` or more equivalent to yours `public string Name { private get; set; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. In this case use a property instead of a public field or explicit setter/getter methods:

```
public class Icon
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Properties are compiled down to setter/getter methods which allows you to change your internal implementation later on if required so still respects encapsulation. Explicit setter/getter methods are not idiomatic for C#.

Also see [MSDN on properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is a clear example of a simple property. Make it a property (not a public field) and assign a value to it:

```
fm.iconData[0].Name = "Plum";
```

Have this property defined like this:

```
public string Name {get;set;}
```

Comment: Just given this a go - perfect. Kinda strange since I can access the properties as if they were public instance variables (which would break encapsulation) - but if this is why properties exist then I'm cool with it.

Comment: Properties look like variables but they can do more if needed. They should stay simple though otherwise should be replaced with methods that return a value.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said, this should be a property. If you plan on adding extra logic to the  property (e.g. validation, raising events), you can define the property like this:

```
public class Icon
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            // custom logic can go here...
            name = value; // value is whatever has been set to this property
        }
    }
}
```

`name` is only visible in the class as it is private. `Name` is visible externally.